# Scikit-learn: linear_model.SGDClassifier(): ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous when calling partial_fit()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to run a linear_model.SGDClassifier() and have it update after every example it classifies.
My code works for a small feature file (10 features), but when I give it a bigger feature file (some 80000 features, but very sparse) it keeps giving me errors straight away, the first time partial_fit() is called.

This is what I do in pseudocode:

```
X, y = load_svmlight_file(train_file)
classifier = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
classifier.fit(X, y)

for every test_line in test file:
  test_X, test_y = getFeatures(test_line)
  # This gives me a Python list for X
  # and an integer label for y

  print "prediction: %f" % = classifier.predict([test_X])

  classifier.partial_fit(csr_matrix([test_X]),
                         csr_matrix([Y_GroundTruth])
                         classes=np.unique(y) )
```

The error I keep getting for the partial_fit() line is:

```
  File "/bla/bla/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 487, in partial_fit
    coef_init=None, intercept_init=None)
  File "/bla/bla/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 371, in _partial_fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight, n_iter=n_iter)
  File "/bla/bla/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 451, in _fit_multiclass
    for i in range(len(self.classes_)))
  File "/bla/bla/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 517, in __call__
    self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
  File "/bla/bla/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 312, in dispatch
    job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
  File "/bla/bla/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/bla/bla/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 284, in fit_binary
    est.power_t, est.t_, intercept_decay)
  File "sgd_fast.pyx", line 327, in sklearn.linear_model.sgd_fast.plain_sgd (sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.c:7568)
ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous
```

I also tried feeding partial.fit() Python arrays, or numpy arrays (which are C-contiguous (sort=C) by default, I thought), but this gives the same result.
The classes attribute is not the problem I think. The same error appears if I leave it out or if I give the right classes in hard code.

I do notice that when I print the flags of the _coef array of the classifier, it says:

```
Flags of coef_ array:
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong, but really, I don't see what...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: OT: `csr_matrix([Y_GroundTruth])` is a bad idea because `y` should be an array, not a sparse matrix. But I thought Peter Prettenhofer already posted a workaround on the scikit-learn mailing list?

Comment: I am sorry, right you are. I somehow didn't get a notification. Here is the [link to the answer](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAD-7WjrodvBhzpNiOe76%3D2JNy9v8EU6%3DHucPKpZ_f3zDZgVQxA%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=scikit-learn-general) in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 3):

For the record (so this question doesn't appear unanswered), this question was [previously answered](http://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/message/31496183/) on the scikit-learn mailing list. It's a bug in scikit-learn 0.14's `SGDClassifier`. The workaround is to replace the initial `fit` with `partial_fit`.

Update: I [fixed the bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/55a2f29ee0042ba855b623baa0b6a9e2ef05da4e) a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: What is the answer? The "previously answered" link doesn't contain the answer.